# Crontab and PATH

Tags: php, path, cron

This is my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
# PHP Script
26 16     * * *   root  /usr/bin/php /var/www/script.php
#
```

Why I should put the full php path (/usr/bin/php) also if there is in PATH variable? Otherwise the script doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because crontab runs under user, who have other value of `PATH`. For more info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/219692/why-the-value-of-path-is-different-for-root-and-normal-user

Comment: But why in the cronfile as you can see PATH variable is specified?